# Taking screenshots on Samsung Galaxy Nexus with Jelly Bean

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, screenshots, 4.1-jelly-bean

Apparently on Ice Cream Sandwich you can press power + volume down to take a screenshot, but this doesn't work for me with Jelly Bean. Anyone know how to take a screenshot on a stock Galaxy Nexus with Android 4.1?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to press the <kbd>Vol Down</kbd> and <kbd>Power</kbd> buttons together, and hold them for a second or so.

Some users report that it works better if you press both buttons simultaneously, as opposed to one after the other in sequence.

Comment: I tried that, and it didn't work -- held them down for a couple seconds.

Comment: Gave it a few more tries and finally got it to work. I just got this phone on Friday, so I just need to get used to it I guess. Cheers

Comment: If Chahk edits his answer, I can upvote it again -- marked it as the answer for now.

Comment: We cab deduce the fact that he has been doing it successfully in ICS so he knows how to do it. He has also mentioned stock ROM so custom ROM possibility doesn't exists. Maybe there is hardware button problem?

Comment: I was having trouble as well, but I had success while pressing and holding the down and power buttons simultaneously!